# Whats the most efficient Way to Code this WordPress Loop(s)?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm just learning to write WP templates [with Pods] and I think there is a more efficient way to code the if/while loops in the example below...? ie: Chaining the while?

An explanation **EDIT: and Code Example** would be appreciated in helping my learning curve. Thnx.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: myPage Template
*/

get_header();
$mypod = pods('my_events');
$mypod->find('name ASC');
?>

<div>

    <?php while ( $mypod->fetch() ) : ?>

        <?php
          // set our variables
          $snippet= $mypod->field('event_snippet');
        ?>

        <p><?php echo $snippet; ?></p>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) :the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>

</div>

<?php endwhile; endif; get_footer(); ?>
```

What I am thinking can be done simular to [but anything I try breaks]:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: myPage Template
*/

get_header();

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $mypod->fetch() ) : ( have_posts() ) :the_post();
$mypod = pods('my_events');
$mypod->find('name ASC');
$snippet= $mypod->field('event_snippet');
?>

<div>

    <p><?php echo $snippet; ?></p>
    <?php the_content(); ?>

</div>

<?php endwhile; endif; get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Screw performance, til you fix the loop that's generating invalid HTML.  :P  (That `endwhile;` and `endif;` should be inside the div.)

Comment: @cHao Interesting because that is how I got it directly from one of Wp's examples -But I'll do that anyways :)

Comment: For reference, your edit is using a nonexistent `$mypod`.  Even if you fix that, the loop has the pod getting looked up again for each post.

Comment: @cHao Thnx - I didnt realize it was duplicating tru all posts.  Plz see the edit above 'and Code Example'.